# journalctl log disappear?

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

Service is still active:

```
systemctl -l status foo.service
● foo.service - My Foo service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/foo.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Fri 2019-01-18 00:08:45 EST; 18h ago
 Main PID: 29032 (bash)
   CGroup: /system.slice/foo.service
           ├─ 4159 ssh: /root/....
```

This morning I was able to tail the logs with `-f -u foo.service`. But now I see this instead:

```
sudo journalctl -u foo.service
-- No entries --

sudo journalctl -f -u foo.service
-- Logs begin at Wed 2019-01-16 10:18:52 EST. --
```

I have another service (well, a timer to be exact) completed and log is also unavailable now.

How do I view old logs? I've tried using `--since yesterday` and `_PID=` for example, and it only returns to me system logs.

Comment: I hope it's not the [recent bug/exploit](https://www.qualys.com/2019/01/09/system-down/system-down.txt)

Comment: How have you proven that any journal entries at all prior to Wednesday even exist any more?  How have you determined where your journal has rotated to?

Comment: @JdeBP that's part of my question I am guessing: it seems like default on CentOS is saving to /run/log which according to some thread here it's volatile and not persistent.